# BULKIO Large Packets Failing

Tags: redhawksdr

I am trying to send packets larger than 2 MB using BULKIO.  I have modified giopMaxMsgSize in /etc/omniORB.cfg to be 8388608, but I am still receiving the following error message: "Call to pushPacket by BULKIO_dataFloat_Out_i failed".  Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the omniORB logging level (see REDHAWK documentation, [Appendix H, section 3](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainap8.html#x34-433000H.3)). It can generate an awful lot of debug info, but it might help you narrow down your problem.

I tried this using two C++ components and was able to push large (> 2MB) BULKIO float packets by adjusting the omniORB.cfg property you had mentioned. Were you also using C++? Redhawk 1.9.0?

Comment: Using c++ and 1.84.  Plan to move to 1.9 soon.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this type of error will occur when the total amount of data exceeds your giopMaxMsgSize, size in total bytes. If we do the math 8388608/4 = 2097152 float values, where there are 4 bytes in a float. Therefore your vector cannot exceed 2097152 real samples, or 1048576 complex samples.

The one method it check this would be to LOG the size of the output vector before calling push.